# Unirest (Mashape) post request with binary response contains special symbols

Tags: java, postman, unirest

I have difficulties executing post request that is supposed to return csv file using unirest (mashape).
When I execute the request with postman I get status 200 and raw response body contains following:

[image]

As soon as I click on save response and download it on my local file system I do not see the symbols in the downloaded file:

"Entity Type","TOTAL ACCOUNTS"
"ACC","25"

For my post request with unirest I am using `.asBinary()` method for the `HttpResponse` but it seems that the byte array contains the same symbols represented by empty space. Here is my method:

```
 private void checkResponseBinary(HttpResponse<InputStream> response, int expectedStatusCode) {
        Integer responseStatusCode = response.getStatus();
        InputStream responseBody = response.getBody();
        String body = "";
        try {
            body = IOUtils.toString(responseBody, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (responseStatusCode != expectedStatusCode) {
             throw new RuntimeException(
        "Actual response status code " + responseStatusCode + " is not equal to expected " + 
          expectedStatusCode
          + ". Body: " + responseBody);
       }
  }
```

At  this point `body` String variable contains this:

[image]

When I write this content to file it looks even worse. The empty spaces are replaced with `NUL`:

[image]

I want the content of the csv file to look like the downloaded file from postman:
"Entity Type","TOTAL ACCOUNTS" "ACC","25"

Comment: do you mean you want to see raw csv response on postman in format similar to CSV?

Comment: When I save the response from postman in separate file it seems OK. The button is "Save Response" (first screenshot). I want to save the same file without any special symbols using unirest for the post request.